# How to deserialize JSON to a dynamic object in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, json.net, silverlight-5.0

I want to deserialize a JSON string to a dynamic object in Silverlight using the Newtonsoft.JSON library.

The JSON string is defined as follows:

```
{"id":42,"longName":"Doe, John","userName":"JD1","domainName":"COMPANY","sid":"A-1-2-34-5678901234-5678901234-5678901234"}
```

Everything I tried did not work. First attempt was to simply use `JObject.Parse` as it is mentioned [here](http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/c-dynamic-object-and-json-serialization-with-json-net/):

```cs
dynamic person = JObject.Parse(myJsonString);
var personId = person.id;
```

Line 2 crashes, because *'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'id'*, although the debugger shows that my JSON string has been deserialized just fine.

Second approach using `JsonConverter.DeserializeObject` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19379838/1521227) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23520523/1521227):

```cs
dynamic person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(myJsonString);
var personId = person.id;
```

I am going to repeat myself but line 2 crashes, because *'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'id'*, although the debugger shows that my JSON string has been deserialized just fine.

Final approach: Define my own derivate of `DynamicObject` using a dictionary to internally manage the properties values [as outlined in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) together with the `JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType` method:

```cs
dynamic person = new DObject();
JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(result, person);
var id = person.id;
```

This again fails because my dynamic object does not get populated.

**So how do I actually deserialize a JSON string to a dynamic object in Silverlight?**

Comment: can you show us the code behind **DObject** class?

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic It is an exact copy of the `DynamicDictionary` class as shown in the example code in the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I linked in the question.