# How to translate json string to object with dynamic names

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

Hello stackoverflow,

What I want is this string into a class in c#.
The part I can't find out is how to make a class of bar.

I receive sting names and want to convert it to a string of names with classes inside of them

```c#
{
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "foo": [
            {
                "keys": "values"
            }
        ],
        "bar": [
            {
                "keys": "values"
            } 
        ]
}
```

This is how this class would look like

```html
public class Foo
{
    public string key{ get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string key{ get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Foo> foo { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> bar { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I wish the class would look like

```html
public class Foos
{
    public string key{ get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Dictionary<String, Foos> foo { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505096/deserialize-json-with-dynamic-objects/23520523#23520523

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON with dynamic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505096/deserialize-json-with-dynamic-objects)

Comment: In other words you want a dictionary instead of two lists? What should happens if lists have different sizes?

Comment: @PeteGarafano thank you Pete, that is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @Kapein no problem!

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @PeteGarafano I have one issue with the code you did send, it says 

City = x.First()["id"], State = x.Last()["state"].

I need 10 variable names, First() and Last() wont cut it