# Deserialize nested, complex json object to just a string c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have JSON which looks like:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "settings": {
    "setting1": true,
    "setting2": 1
  }
}
```

I know how to use json2csharp.com to create the C# classes to deserialize this. They looks like:

```
public class Settings
{
    public bool settings1 { get; set; }
    public int settings2 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Settings settings { get; set; }
}
```

but what I want is to simply deserialize it into

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string settings { get; set; }
}
```

i.e., all of the "setting" JSON just needs to be saved as a string--the structure of that JSON is not consistent. How can that be done? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of going to a string (unless this is really what you want), you could probably get this to go into some sort of dictionary. I answered something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505096/deserialize-json-with-dynamic-objects/23520523#23520523

Comment: @PeteGarafano. I do need it as a string, you I think that you have the right idea. I just need to do it like:

`code`
var rawObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
var uniq = rawObj.name;
var settings = rawObj.settings;
`code`
thanks for the idea

Comment: @John see my answer, I don't think using dynamic here is the "cleanest" solution.

Comment: @John I did it with `dynamic` in that answer, but nothing is stopping you from making it into a `Dictionary<string, string>` or something similar. If it helped at all, I'll call it a win. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `JToken` to capture your unknown `settings` during deserialization, then use a second property to allow you to access that JSON as a string if you need to.

Set up your class like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Settings
    {
        get { return SettingsToken != null ? SettingsToken.ToString(Formatting.None) : null; }
        set { SettingsToken = value != null ? JToken.Parse(value) : JValue.CreateNull(); }
    }

    [JsonProperty("settings")]
    private JToken SettingsToken { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize as usual:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

The `Settings` property will contain the `settings` part of the JSON as a string.  If you reserialize the object back to JSON then the `settings` will retain whatever structure it had before.

You can also change the `Settings` property to some other JSON string, as long as it is well-formed. (If it isn't, then an exception will be thrown immediately.)

Here is a round-trip demo:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/thiaWk

Comment: Brilliant! This works perfectly and I was able to easily adapt this for another challenge I had. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try using Newtonsoft.Json plus LINQ:

```
string jsonText = @"{
            'name': 'foo',
            'settings': {
                'settings1': true,
                'settings2': 1
                }
            }";

JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
var setting = jObj.Descendants()
                .OfType<JProperty>()
                .Where(p => p.Name == "settings")
                .First()
                .Value.ToObject<Settings>();
```

Comment: This would work, but Brian's solution is better for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class RootObject
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string,object> settings { get; set; }
        }
```

Fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/QN3nWL

Comment: I can't redefine the RootObject like this and the real object is more complex and it will not always go into a Dictionary, but +1 for the dotnetfiddle. I like those!

Comment: @John why can't it go to dictionary? Dictionary<string,object> represents any object structure in .NET

Comment: Yes, it does work to parse the json, but I really need to leave that as a string property.

Answer (score 0):

I have just this solution:

```
public class RootObject
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public Settings settings { get; set; }
            public string strSettings { get; set; } <-------- 
        }
```

and

```
  var data= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    data.strSettings = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.settings);
```

Comment: This wont work. He said the structure of the Settings is not consistent so you can't use a Settings class like that.